# Melted chocolate wafers

Tags: butter, cocoa, chips

When I make crunchie bars my melted chocolate that covers them goes white if I put them in the fridge. Will cocoa butter chips help that issue. I'm not sure why the chocolate goes milky white on areas.  If I add cocoa butter chips make a difference

Answer (score 3):

Chocolate turns white due to "fat bloom", that is, the fat content of the chocolate wanders to the surface and crystallizes into this white bloom that you observe. This can be avoided if you cool your chocolate in a cool, but not cold spot. 18 °C or about 65 F seems to be the sweet spot for this. Source [here](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/05/x-rays-reveal-how-chocolate-turns-white).

Alternatively, you could try to reduce the fat content by using chocolate with a lower cocoa butter/fat content.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to temper your chocolate this website covers how to do that and why it needs to be done in exhaustive detail: http://www.cookingforengineers.com/article/155/Tempering-Chocolate